# U-boot Makefile option on ARM

Tags: gcc, makefile, u-boot

I need an U-boot asm file, "Uboot.s", from "gcc -S" command. but I don't know how to get this ".s" file. I used "Objdump -d uboot" command and got a asm code, but this file can't build to binary after modifying asm.

If I want to set "gcc -S" option for compiling u-boot, which part would I edit in Makefile?
I got u-boot sources from "git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git". And It will be on omap5432 environment. Here are commands I used for compiling u-boot.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- distclean
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- omap5_uevm_deconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-
```

Comment: Don't you normally change compile flags with CFLAGS?

Comment: I used "make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- CFLAGS=-S" command. But I couldn't find an u-boot.s file in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the top-level Makefile in U-boot sources and add this line:

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -S
```